# Use @types definitions in project .d.ts definition file

Tags: typescript, types, node-modules

I'm trying to write a .d.ts file for my project to define some global interfaces.
However I have a problem using non-global library types inside that definition file.
Especially RxJs which I'm trying to reference does not work for me.

The thing I thought would work the best was using a triple-slash reference tag to import the types for RxJs, however this didn't work.

```
/// <reference types="rxjs" />

interface IUserService {
    user$: rxjs.Observable<IUser>;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution to what I wanted to do:

```
import RxJs from 'rxjs';

declare global {

    interface IUserService {
        user$: RxJs.Observable<IUser>;
    }

}
```

Using `declare global { }` I was able to get back into the global namespace.
Typescript is really lacking documentation on this useful directive which is only documented slightly at the end of this page: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation.